# how to read xml data from a DATASET object in c#

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I just used this code to read xml data from an XML file.It successfully reads the data from file.I Just want to know how can I read SelectSingleNode data from an xml dataset.

```
public DataSet ds =new DataSet();
public FileStream stream = null;

stream = new FileStream(schdlpath, FileMode.Open);
ds.ReadXml(stream);

//after this even if i delete the xml file it won't hamper the appliaction.
stream.Close();

//this way I can print all the data..
Console.WriteLine(ds.GetXml());
```

All I want is to read the data
like this

```
public XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode ht = document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Schedule/AudioVedioPlayer/Height");
```

Actually I want to read the xml data and store it into a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(ds.GetXml());
XmlNode ht = document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Schedule/AudioVedioPlayer/Height");
```

Comment: thnx4 help,bt can i Read That data from dataset...??

Comment: THnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...Just applied on a demo apps.going to add to the big one.wish me luck....n also sorrry f my thnx seems small to u...... I really meant it big way.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the xml from the dataset into a stream and then use the stream to read it into an XmlDocument object. From there, you can use the DOM to navigate.

Now, are you trying to store a part of the data, as XML, into a variable? Or are you looking for the height value? If the former, I have no issue with your plan. If the later, I assume, from looking at your XPath statement (SelectSingleNode()) that you have the following:

DataSet:  Schedule
Table:    AudioVedioPlayer
Property: Height

If I am correct about your setup, then you can easily get to the value you require by drilling down into the DataSet.

```
public DataSet ds =new DataSet(); 
public FileStream stream = null;
stream = new FileStream(schdlpath, FileMode.Open); 
ds.ReadXml(stream);
```

You can then get to the table:

```
ScheduleTable table = ds.Schedule;
```

And get the value

```
int height = table.Height;
```

Or you can just shortcut it

```
int height = ds.Schedule.Height;
```

No reason to get XML unless you want an entire section of XML.